# How to manage opening and closing database connections while working with activerecords and multiple threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

I am trying to implement a multithreaded method in rails such that I can create/update multiple records very quickly.

This is the outline of my program.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  (1..10).each do |i|
    arr[i] = Thread.new {
       <some logic on obj>
       ...
       ...
       obj.save! 
    }
  end
  arr.each {|t| t.join}
end
```

This gives me warnings on my log.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Database connections will not be closed automatically, 
please close your database connection at the end of the thread by calling `close`
on your connection.
```

And it gives me an error

```
could not obtain a database connection within 5 seconds (waited 5.059358 seconds). 
The max pool size is currently 5; consider increasing it.
```

I tried:
 - changing database.yaml and increasing the poolsize and timeout there. 
 - modified the existing code in the following way.

```
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.clear_stale_cached_connections!
   begin
     ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        (1..10).each do |i|
          arr[i] = Thread.new {
             <some logic on obj>
             ...
             ...
             obj.save!
             ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close 
          }
        end
        arr.each {|t| t.join}
     end
   ensure
     ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close if ActiveRecord::Base.connection
     ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections!
   end
```

I am still getting the same warning and error.
I am obviously missing the concept here. How do I proceed with this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To prevent connection leak in multi threads, you have to manage the connection manually. You can try:

```
Thread.new do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    # Do whatever
  end
end
```

One problem of `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection` is that it always prepare a connection even if the code inside does not need it.

We can improve it a little bit by using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.release_connection`:

```
Thread.new do
  begin
    # Do whatever
  ensure
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.release_connection
  end
end
```

Comment: This method only works for connections that have been obtained through connection or with_connection methods, connections obtained through checkout will not be automatically released.

source:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html#method-i-connection

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run in N threads, make sure you have N connections in the pool

```
#  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config
#  # => {pool: 5, timeout: 5000, database: "db/development.sqlite3", adapter: "sqlite3"}
```

otherwise you will be able to fetch a connection from [the pool](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb).