# Rails ActiveRecord with_connection idle db connections leaked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, postgresql, activerecord, database-connection

I have a small rails app that spawns new threads to update itself in the background until a certain condition is met.

```
class SomeModel < ApplicationRecord
  def self.some_action
    if some_condition
      Thread.new do
        begin
          sleep some_arbitrary_time
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
            update(attr_x: true)
            some_action
          end
        ensure
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.release_connection
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have tried `ActiveRecord::with_connection` `releasing` `closing` connections, but in the end, there are always idle connections.

Checking the db or ActiveRecord show several idle connections

```
db_development=# select state from pg_stat_activity where pid <> pg_backend_pid();
 state
-------
 idle
 idle
 idle
 idle

ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat
{"size":10,"connections":5,"busy":1,"dead":0,"idle":4,"waiting":0,"checkout_timeout":5}
```

It is my understanding that the `reaping` process only takes care of dead connections, idle connections will stay there consuming pool resources.

A more simple example (based of a particular [rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14470)) shows that there are idle processes after the use of new Threads and `with_connection`.

Before the test

```
collab-playlist_development=# select state from pg_stat_activity where pid <> pg_backend_pid();
 state
-------
(0 rows)

20.times.map do 
  Thread.new do 
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do 
      SomeModel.count 
      end 
    end 
  end
```

After the test

```
db_development=# select state from pg_stat_activity where pid <> pg_backend_pid();
 state
-------
 idle
 idle
 idle
 idle
 idle
 idle
 idle
 idle
 idle
 idle

ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.stat
{"size":10,"connections":10,"busy":0,"dead":0,"idle":10,"waiting":0,"checkout_timeout":5}
```

Is there a way to close those idle connections to free up pool resources?

Some references (aside from the rails doc) that shed some light into this issue, but no resolution:

SO

- [How to manage opening and closing database connections while working with activerecords and multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596183/how-to-manage-opening-and-closing-database-connections-while-working-with-active/26733385)
- [Connection pool issue with ActiveRecord objects in rufus-scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248808/connection-pool-issue-with-activerecord-objects-in-rufus-scheduler)

Blog posts

- [Reliable concurrency with rails](http://engineering.midtrans.com/reliable-concurrency-with-rails/)
- [Avoid leaked connections rails 4](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/activerecord-concurrency-in-rails4-avoid-leaked-connections/)

Comment: Did you find solution? And which server are you using? We think we are seeing this with Phusion Passenger 6 (free, nginx). Did not have this problem in Phusion Passenger 3, the "with_connection do" worked fine and would not eat connections.

Comment: Turns out adding this to database.yml fixed this for us on Phusion Passenger 6:
`reaping_frequency: 120`