# Rails + mySQL + Passenger - Connections to ActiveRecord are not getting closed after request timeout

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm using Passenger with Apache and MySQL as the database. In my production environment, connection are getting closed on their own after request timeout.

I would like to know how to close connection?

Comment: I found something, Maybe helpful for you https://engineering.grab.com/deep-dive-into-database-timeouts-in-rails

Comment: See if this of any [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26733385/4160532).

Comment: I am using wait_timeout in database.yml, but it is not closing the connection after the request is timed out. Any suggestion on this.